# I tried reversing a linked list using an recursion approach but got an segmentation error? What went wrong?

Tags: c++, linked-list, reverse

```
#include <iostream>

class node {
public:
    int data;
    node* next;

    node(int val) : data(val) {
        this->next = nullptr;
    }
};

class linkedlist {
public:
    node* head;

    linkedlist() {
        this->head = nullptr;
    }

    void print() {
        while(head != nullptr) {
            std::cout << head->data << " ";
            head = head->next;
        }
    }

    void push(int val) {

        if (head == nullptr) {
            head = new node(val);
            return;
        }
        node* temp = new node(val);
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }

    // node* recursive_reverse(node* head) {
    //     if (head == nullptr || head->next == nullptr) return head;
    //     node* _rest = recursive_reverse(head->next);
    //     head->next->next = head;
    //     head->next = nullptr;
    //     head = _rest;
    //     return head;
    // }


    node* rr_bourne_again(node* head) {
        if (head->next == nullptr) return head;
        node* temp = new node(0);
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        node* _rest = rr_bourne_again(head->next);
        head->next->next = nullptr;
        head = _rest;
        delete(temp);
        temp = nullptr;
        return head;
    }
};

int main()
{
    linkedlist ll;
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) ll.push(i);

    // ll.head = ll.recursive_reverse(ll.head);
    
    ll.head = ll.rr_bourne_again(ll.head);
    ll.print();
}
```

I intend to push a temp node to the head of the list, making it the new head. Then I separate the list into two parts - the new head node and the rest, namely the original list. I would reverse the rest list then link it to a nullptr. Finally I would free up the memory allocated to temp node.

I was expecting something like this in the terminal:
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1%

but something must have went south and i got a segmentation error instead.
zsh: segmentation fault

What went wrong?

Comment: Here's a really handy tool: https://godbolt.org/z/xGnobT5dr If you look at the stacktrace when it crashes it's a pretty clear sign of a stack overflow brought on by uncontrolled recursion in `rr_bourne_again`. Function gets called again and a gain until the system's out of automatic storage. Easiest way to debug that is by stepping through the function with a debugger to see for yourself why the function never exits..

Comment: Side note: Be careful with logic like `if (head->next == nullptr)`. You need to be damn sure that `head`'s not null in order for `head->next` to be valid. I find it's almost always better to just work in terms of `head` itself.

Comment: Side note: One of the best ways to debug a linked list, or any other tree or general graph problem, is to draw pictures of all the steps necessary to perform the transformation you want and then trace through your code, following closely and drawing what the program does to see if you can draw the same pictures. If you can't you know where the bug, or one of them anyway, is and probably have a good idea what you should have done instead to make both pictures the same.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but calling `print()` blows up the list: it uses `head` to iterate through the list, ultimately setting it to a null pointer. Instead of using `head` use a local variable that starts out with the value of `head`: node *current = head; while (current) { std::cout << current->data << ' '; current = current->next; }`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I figured it out the hard way after realizing that the object variable `head` changes every time I run the member function `print`, so I assume that variables are passed by reference within the same object, or is it perhaps because of something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you have commented out a function that would do the job perfectly, so I guess your question is only to know what went wrong with your attempt at it:

Your code first creates a dummy node, then prefixes that node to the current linked list, and then ... passes the node that follows that dummy node as argument to the recursive call. Let's visualise those steps with an example list with values 1 and 2:

```
                     head
                      ↓
                    ┌──────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐
                    │ data: 1      │    │ data: 2      │
                    │ next: ───────────►│ next: nullptr│
                    │              │    │              │
                    └──────────────┘    └──────────────┘
```

`node* temp = new node(0);` creates a new node, so we get this:

```
 temp                head
  ↓                   ↓
┌──────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐
│ data: 0      │    │ data: 1      │    │ data: 2      │
│ next: nullptr│    │ next: ───────────►│ next: nullptr│
│              │    │              │    │              │
└──────────────┘    └──────────────┘    └──────────────┘
```

`temp->next = head;` creates the link:

```
 temp                head
  ↓                   ↓
┌──────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐
│ data: 0      │    │ data: 1      │    │ data: 2      │
│ next: ───────────►│ next: ───────────►│ next: nullptr│
│              │    │              │    │              │
└──────────────┘    └──────────────┘    └──────────────┘
```

...and then it is made the head by `head = temp;`

```
 temp head
  ↓    ↓
┌──────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐
│ data: 0      │    │ data: 1      │    │ data: 2      │
│ next: ───────────►│ next: ───────────►│ next: nullptr│
│              │    │              │    │              │
└──────────────┘    └──────────────┘    └──────────────┘
```

Then the recursive call is made by passing `head->next` as argument, but `head->next` is the node with data 1, so this is what the recursive execution will see:

```
                     head
                      ↓
                    ┌──────────────┐    ┌──────────────┐
                    │ data: 1      │    │ data: 2      │
                    │ next: ───────────►│ next: nullptr│
                    │              │    │              │
                    └──────────────┘    └──────────────┘
```

The new local variable `head` points to the exact same node as the node we started with! So the "problem" of reversal has not been simplified... we didn't make any progress when making the recursive call. NB: I did not depict the dummy node that was created earlier, as this recursive execution context has no access to it, so it isn't relevant.

Now the process continues as from the top, and the only thing that can end this chain of recursive calls is a memory shortage. Most likely stack memory will run out first, but also heap memory is consumed by the dummy nodes that are repeatedly created. Note that there really is no need to create dummy nodes for a list reversal.

The correct code you already have does not pass the same node pointer to the recursive call, but a pointer to a *shorter* list, which guarantees that the recursion will stop at a certain point.

Also, the correct code can cope with an *empty* list, as it tests for `head == nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find it easier to swap the next pointer before recursing. But that means you need to pass head->next->next as well as head->next to each recursive step.

```
node* recursive_reverse_impl(node* left, node* right) {
    if (right == nullptr) {
        return left;
    }

    node* nextRight = right->next;
    right->next = left;
    return recursive_reverse_impl(right, nextRight);
}

 node* recursive_reverse(node* head) {
     node* newHead= recursive_reverse_impl(head, head ? head->next : nullptr);
     if (head) {
         head->next = nullptr;
     }
     return newHead;
 }
```